# Rails 4: text_field for acts_as_taggable_on not separating tags with a comma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

I am trying to get the text_field in my form partial to comma-separate acts_as_taggable_on tags. Right now, when I reload the page, the commas disappear so if a field has two or more tags, they become one big tag instead. For instance, I get "Tag1 Tag2 Tag3" instead of "Tag1, Tag2, Tag3". I am using acts-as-taggable-on 3.4.2.

Here is my **_form.html.erb** partial:

```
<h2>Tags:</h2>
<p>Please separate the tags with a comma ','</p>

<% @article.tag_types.each do |tag| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <strong><%= label_tag tag.to_s.titleize %></strong><br />
    <%= f.text_field "#{tag.to_s.singularize}_list".to_sym, :placeholder => "Comma-separated list of #{tag.to_s}", class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Every time I reload the edit page, the input value somehow removes the commas from the already-present tags, so the text field looks like this:

```
<input id="article_country_list" class="form-control" type="text" name="article[country_list]" value="China U.S.A." placeholder="Comma-separated list of countries">
```

instead of having `value="China, U.S.A."` as it should be.

Here is my model, **article.rb**:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable_on :people, :cities, :countries, :other
end
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Thanks!

Comment: add multiple: true to field_tag

Comment: Doesn't make a difference, the tags are still not being comma separated by default in the text_field when I go to the edit page :(

Answer (score 11):

Apparently this is a [new security feature](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/issues/620).

I solved the comma separation issue by doing:

```
<% @article.tag_types.each do |tag| %>
<div class="form-group">
  <strong><%= f.label tag.to_s.titleize %></strong><br />
  <% tag_sym = "#{tag.to_s.singularize}_list".to_sym %>
  <% tag_list = "#{tag.to_s.singularize}_list" %>
  <%= f.text_field tag_sym, value: @article.send(tag_list).to_s, :placeholder => "Comma-separated list of #{tag.to_s}", class: 'form-control' %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks! Since I am using ActiveAdmin with Formtastic I made a custom input.

So I created a new class: app/inputs/tag_list_input.rb with:

```
class TagListInput < Formtastic::Inputs::StringInput
  def input_html_options
    super.merge(:value => "#{@object.send(method).to_s.html_safe}")
  end
end
```

and using this like:

```
f.input :some_tag_list, :as => :tag_list, :label => "SomeTags"
```