# Rails - acts_as_taggable_on Removes Commas When Editing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delimiter, acts-as-taggable-on

I have successfully set up acts_as_taggable_on my model. As expected, when I split the tags with commas, it splits the tags correctly.

However, when I edit the post the field is auto populated with the tags for editing, except the commas are now gone.

This means if I hit save without putting them back in, the tags now become all one tag.

I have tried using `ActsAsTaggableOn.delimiter = ' '` which works when they are one word tags. But now I have the issue that if i have a two word tag, when I edit and save the post the two word tags now become one word tags.

Any help anybody might have on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Try this in the form input: `<%= f.text_field :tag_list, value: @example_record.tag_list.join(",") %>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 4: text\_field for acts\_as\_taggable\_on not separating tags with a comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27646714/rails-4-text-field-for-acts-as-taggable-on-not-separating-tags-with-a-comma)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This behavior is apparently [by design](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/issues/620) in acts_as_taggable_on.

Try adding `to_s` to your tag_list in the form input:

```
<%= f.text_field :tag_list, value: @example_record.tag_list.to_s %>
```

Not ideal, but this should allow your field to display the comma separated tags properly.

Comment: Ah! Worked a treat! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

For simple_form use this:

```
<%= f.input :tag_list, input_html: {value: @example_record.tag_list.to_s} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using just one word in your tags, you can use a space as a delimiter instead of commas.

```
config/initializers/acts_as_taggable_on.rb  

ActsAsTaggableOn.delimiter = ' ' # use space as delimiter
```

I think this is not ideal too, but solved the problem.