# Rails acts_as_taggable, tags losing comma on edit!? becomes one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tags, acts-as-taggable-on

I am using acts_as_taggable_on gem with Rails 4.2 and I have a form where you can enter tags, seperated by commas.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label(:tag_list, "Tags (seperated by commas)") %><br />
  <%= f.text_field(:tag_list, :class=>"formbox")%>
</div>
```

The tags work fine, but when I go back to an article and edit it, the commas that were previously there disappear! For example, if I input tags:

> white, light, soft

When I edit, those 3 separate tags will become 1 tag:

> white light soft

Does anybody know what's happening here? It sucks to lose all those tags, I want to be able to keep all those tags upon edit.

Comment: Doing a 5 minute-research I found this: https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/issues/620 . Maybe google first next time? :D You might have found this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 4: text\_field for acts\_as\_taggable\_on not separating tags with a comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27646714/rails-4-text-field-for-acts-as-taggable-on-not-separating-tags-with-a-comma)

Answer (score 13):

simple_form:

```
<%= f.input :tag_list, :label => "Tags* (seperated by commas)", :input_html => { :class => "css-class", :value => @article.tag_list.join(", ") } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for this by adding "," between each tag item. Which can be done like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label(:tag_list, "Tags* (seperated by commas)") %><br />
      <%= f.text_field(:tag_list, value: @article.tag_list.join(","))%>
</div>
```